# Disord.py - How to list all servers the bot is in?

Tags: python, list, directory, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make it so my bot when it comes online it will check for every server the bot is on and create a folder for them in a directory but i keep getting the error list2 is not defined even though iv defined it here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

PREFIX = "$"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX, description="Hi")

list1 = os.listdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BOT_FOLDER')
for guild in bot.guilds:
    print(guild.name)
    list2 = guild.name


print(os.listdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BOT_FOLDER'))

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

missing = list(sorted(set1 - set2))
added = list(sorted(set2 - set1))

print('missing:', missing)
print('added:', added)

newpath = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\BOT_FOLDER\{}'.format(added)
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

if os.path.exists("demofile.txt"):
  os.remove('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BOT_FOLDER/{}').format(missing)
else:
  print("The file does not exist")

bot.run('BOT_TOKEN_HERE')
```

Comment: list2 is local variable and is only visible inside that for loop, make it global

Answer (score 1):

Actually the interpreter is right! Even if it doesn't seem like it, `list2` isn't defined, when you run `set2 = set(list2)`.

---

### Why this is the case

You're bascially calling `for guild in bot.guilds` right after the initialization of your `bot` object. However, it hasn't connnected to the API yet, which means it hasn't loaded things like `bot.guilds`. This attribute will be `None`, therefore your loop doesn't run and `list2` won't get defined.

---

### How to fix this

Wait until your bot is successfully connected to the API, and **then** iterate over your guilds. This can be done by using the `on_ready()` event. Also, you need to `.append()` items to a list, you can't just assign new items with the equal sign.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    list1 = os.listdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BOT_FOLDER')
    list2 = []
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(guild.name)
        list2.append(guild.name)


    print(os.listdir('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BOT_FOLDER'))

    set1 = set(list1)
    set2 = set(list2)

    missing = list(sorted(set1 - set2))
    added = list(sorted(set2 - set1))

    print('missing:', missing)
    print('added:', added)

    newpath = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\BOT_FOLDER\{}'.format(added)
    if not os.path.exists(newpath):
        os.makedirs(newpath)

    if os.path.exists("demofile.txt"):
        os.remove('C:/Users/User/Desktop/BOT_FOLDER/{}').format(missing)
    else:
        print("The file does not exist")
```